# Excel, turning a zero to a different number automatically.

Tags: microsoft-excel

What would be the best way to convert a 0 ( zero ) to .01 ?
i have looked at conditional formatting, hex2dec etc.  I know there is a simple answer.... just stumped at the moment.

This would need to be for multiple rows/columns....

Comment: do you want to change the value of all cells from `0` to `0.01`?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question is lacking details needed for anyone to be able to help you. Please add details of what your data is like, what you have tried so far, and if this is just a one time thing or something you want to do on a repeated basis. If you need more help about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: yes, 0 to 0.01  @Divin3

Comment: After reading @teylyn's answer it occurs to me to also ask the question why you want 0 to become .01?  If the answer to that is to avoid division by zero error's the you really should be asking a different question-there are better solutions than changing 0 to .01

Comment: @Tyson  The value is from intervals for each half hour of a day, When the program gives me a 0, i have to go in to excel and manually change each 0 to .01, so to be able to copy and paste into a section, and have all the 0 change to .01 would save me time and accuracy.

Comment: What is "half hour of a day"? 12 hours? And why would that be a value of 0? Can you edit your question to have more context and verbose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the portion of the worksheet you wish to convert and run this short macro:

```
Sub NotQuiteZero()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If r.Text = "0" Then r.Value = 0.01
    Next r
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

- Find and replace
- Worksheet_Change event VBA routine
- entering the value correctly in the first place,

You must realize that 0 and 0.01 are different values and no amount of formatting will turn one value into the other.

If you need more details for a particular approach, edit your question and describe the scenario, then post a comment.

Comment: The value is from intervals for each half hour of a day, When the program gives me a 0, i have to go in to excel and manually change each 0 to .01, so to be able to copy and paste into a section, and have all the 0 change to .01 would save me time and accuracy. Entering the correct value in the first place isnt possible. @teylyn

Comment: What part of "Edit your question" is difficult to understand?

Comment: Please, you dont have to respond to any part of this question, go be rude to someone else....

Comment: It's difficult to write instructions for somebody who is not willing to follow instructions. You've been pointed to resources about site etiquette by several people. Ignoring *that* is rude.